# Using a PHLivePhoto with a UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity, apple-live-photos

Trying to share as activity a PHLivePhoto within a UIActivityViewController without any result more than the console output:

- Resource not found (3 times logged)

I use the PHLivePhoto request with local URL's from document directory: Both files are already there. I set a PHLivePhotoView with the completion Live Photo witch works fine and I can reproduce/replay without any issues.

```
 PHLivePhoto.request(withResourceFileURLs: [ URL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath + "/IMG.MOV"), URL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath + "/IMG.JPG")],
                                    placeholderImage: nil,
                                    targetSize: self!.view.bounds.size,
                                    contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFit,
                                    resultHandler: { (livePhoto, info) -> Void in
                                        self?.livePhotoView.livePhoto = livePhoto
                                        self?.exportLivePhoto()
                })
```

The problem is that I'm not quite sure what should be the content of the activity, I've try without any results:

```
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self.livePhotoView.livePhoto], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Been trying to fill as activity items with:

- URL Document path (where video and image exist)
- Both URLS from image and video (reverse order)
- LivePhoto itself (as code below)
- Trying to delay the LivePhoto creation as other people may suggest.

Comment: content of the activity vc should be simple image (UIImage object), you can not share live photo as is

Comment: I think thats not quite right since you can from Photos and Airdrop, even create a Watchface.